# trying to widen a dataframe, while interacting two columns by their factors

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, pipe, tidyr

So here's my reproducible example Data frame, I have a year column and a column of cancers, both are factors and I'm trying to widen the data frame while interacting them. it's a little complicated to explain so I showed both the original and final data frame. Basically, I'm trying to get individual cancer tallies separated by year.

Ideally this would be done with pipes since that's what I'm more familiar with and can tweak for my actual data frame, which is 10 year levels and 15 cancer levels, as well as 10 levels in a second column that I want to give the same treatment to.

```
YR<-as.factor( c(2019,2018,2019,2019,2018,2018,2019,2019,2018))
STATE<-as.factor( c("CA","MA","KY","KY","CA","MA","KY","KY","CA"))
COUNTY<-as.factor( c("C1","M1","K1","K2","C1","M2","K1","K2","C1"))
CANCER<-as.factor(c("Cervical","Lung","Prostate","Breast","Cervical","Breast","Prostate","Prostate","Lung"))
rand_fact<-as.factor(c("rf1","rf2","rf3","fr4","fr5","rf2","rf3","fr4","fr5"))
rand_num<-as.numeric(c(4,3,5,7,3,5,3,24,9))
rand_chr<-as.character(c("a","d","r","e","g","y","r","e","k"))
TEST_DR<-data.frame(YR,STATE,COUNTY,CANCER,rand_fact,rand_num,rand_chr)
rm(YR,STATE,COUNTY,CANCER,rand_chr,rand_num,rand_fact)
TEST_DR<-arrange(.data = TEST_DR,YR,COUNTY)

> print(TEST_DR)
  YR STATE COUNTY   CANCER rand_fact rand_num rand_chr
2018    CA     C1 Cervical       fr5        3        g
2018    CA     C1     Lung       fr5        9        k
2018    MA     M1     Lung       rf2        3        d
2018    MA     M2   Breast       rf2        5        y
2019    CA     C1 Cervical       rf1        4        a
2019    KY     K1 Prostate       rf3        5        r
2019    KY     K1 Prostate       rf3        3        r
2019    KY     K2   Breast       fr4        7        e
2019    KY     K2 Prostate       fr4       24        e
```

So looking at the table below you'll see that there is a set of cancer columns for 2018 and a separate set for 2019. with some row totalling as we go.

```
STATE<-as.factor( c("CA","MA","MA","KY","KY"))
COUNTY<-as.factor( c("C1","M1","M2","K1","K2"))
Cervical_18<-as.numeric(c(1,0,0,0,0))
Lung_18<-as.numeric(c(1,1,0,0,0))
Prostate_18<-as.numeric(c(0,0,0,0,0))
Breast_18<-as.numeric(c(0,0,1,0,0))
Cervical_19<-as.numeric(c(1,0,0,0,0))
Lung_19<-as.numeric(c(0,0,0,0,0))
Prostate_19<-as.numeric(c(0,0,0,2,1))
Breast_19<-as.numeric(c(0,0,0,0,1))
total_C18<-as.numeric(c(2,1,1,0,0))
total_C19<-as.numeric(c(1,0,0,2,2))
total_cancer<-as.numeric(c(3,1,1,2,2))
TEST_DR3 <-data.frame(STATE,COUNTY,Cervical_18,Lung_18,Prostate_18,
                                             Breast_18,total_C18,Cervical_19,Lung_19,Prostate_19,
                                             Breast_19,total_C19,total_cancer)
rm(STATE,COUNTY,Cervical_18,Lung_18,Prostate_18,
              Breast_18,total_C18,Cervical_19,Lung_19,Prostate_19,
              Breast_19,total_C19,total_cancer)

> print(TEST_DR3)
   STATE COUNTY Cervical_18 Lung_18 Prostate_18 Breast_18 total_C18 Cervical_19  Lung_19  Prostate_19  Breast_19  total_C19  total_cancer
1    CA     C1           1       1           0         0         2           1        0            0          0          1             3
2    MA     M1           0       1           0         0         1           0        0            0          0          0             1
3    MA     M2           0       0           0         1         1           0        0            0          0          0             1
4    KY     K1           0       0           0         0         0           0        0            2          0          2             2
5    KY     K2           0       0           0         0         0           0        0            1          1          2             2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

TEST_DR %>%                                # v-----------set this to "value" so that later we don't need to specify the column name for the argument "values_from"
  count(YR, STATE, COUNTY, CANCER, name = "value") %>%
  rows_insert(
    (.) %>% 
      group_by(STATE, COUNTY, YR) %>% 
      summarise(CANCER = "total", value = sum(value)),
    by = c("STATE", "COUNTY", "YR", "CANCER")
  ) %>% 
  arrange(YR, factor(CANCER, unique(CANCER))) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(STATE, COUNTY), 
    names_from = c(CANCER, YR), 
    values_fn = sum, 
    values_fill = 0L
  ) %>% 
  mutate(total_cancer = rowSums(across(starts_with("total"))))
```

Output

```
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'STATE', 'COUNTY' (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 5 x 11
  STATE COUNTY Cervical_2018 Lung_2018 Breast_2018 total_2018 Cervical_2019 Breast_2019 Prostate_2019 total_2019 total_cancer
  <fct> <fct>          <int>     <int>       <int>      <int>         <int>       <int>         <int>      <int>        <dbl>
1 CA    C1                 1         1           0          2             1           0             0          1            3
2 MA    M1                 0         1           0          1             0           0             0          0            1
3 MA    M2                 0         0           1          1             0           0             0          0            1
4 KY    K2                 0         0           0          0             0           1             1          2            2
5 KY    K1                 0         0           0          0             0           0             2          2            2
```

---

Or using `reshape2::dcast`

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

TEST_DR %>% 
  count(YR, STATE, COUNTY, CANCER, name = "value") %>% 
  rows_insert(
    (.) %>% 
      group_by(STATE, COUNTY, YR) %>% 
      summarise(CANCER = "total", value = sum(value)),
    by = c("STATE", "COUNTY", "YR", "CANCER")
  ) %>% 
  arrange(YR, factor(CANCER, unique(CANCER))) %>% 
  dcast(STATE + COUNTY ~ CANCER + YR, sum) %>% 
  mutate(total_cancer = rowSums(across(starts_with("total"))))
```

Comment: this was really helpful thank you! do you have an Idea for doing  the totals though?